# M-x sometimes doesn't show me the right options (smex?)

Tags: ido, m-x, flx-ido

This is most likely a problem with a plugin (caching options, using LRU, etc?), but I'm not good enough to really troubleshoot it. My complete dotfiles (not very extensive) can be found [here](https://github.com/Trevoke/dotfiles/tree/master/.emacs.d)

I use the following related plugins (and maybe others, but I'm not sure):

- flx-ido
- smex
- ido-ubiquitous
- ido-vertical-mode

What seems to be happening is the following:

1. I press `C-x C-m` (globally bound to `'smex`)
2. I type `lt` which finds `load-theme`
3. I choose a theme
4. Everything works
5. I press `C-x C-m`
6. I type `ruby`
7. I see absolutely nothing in the list
8. I type `C-g` to get out of it
9. I type `C-x C-m`
10. I type `ruby`
11. I see a lot of ruby options

I should see a host of ruby-related things, including for instance `ruby-mode`.

Comment: Is `ruby-mode` loaded? Can you look it up with `C-h f ruby-mode`?

Comment: I use those same packages, without an issue. In addition to CQQLs question, does `ruby-mode` work when doing straight old `M-x`? Does it consistently fail to show up using smex?

Comment: Works for me. Have you tried bisecting your configuration? If the problem persists with just `smex` loaded, file a bug report.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that it does "work".

Comment: @Dmitry I'm guessing you mean working my way through the changes in the configuration to figure out which one broke it? I was hoping this had happened to someone.. But I can do that, I just don't have the time to seriously do that for a while, I think.

Comment: There is an SMex issue that sounds remotely similar to your problem: https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex/issues/37

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the value of `smex-auto-update`?  The default is `t`.

```
smex-auto-update is a compiled Lisp function in `smex.el'.
(smex-auto-update &optional IDLE-TIME)
Update Smex when Emacs has been idle for IDLE-TIME.
```

Comment: It's still set to `t`. I haven't changed it.